# Dotnetnuke You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page

Tags: google-maps-api-3, dotnetnuke

I am using DNN 7.3 and Porto theme.

I am getting error in console:

> You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page.
>   This may cause unexpected errors.

I also get warning

> Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys.

I am including it in Google-recommended way, with my API key:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my_api_key&callback=my_callbak_function" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In page source I see

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

which was added by DNN (or Porto theme) and this is the cause of the problem, but **I cannot find where and how to disable it (or edit so it includes my api key).**

I dont have much experience with DNN so any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Checking with the theme developer us usually the best approach.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Craig. I have contacted theme developer (we purchased this theme) and now waiting for their reply.

Answer (score 0):

I received a DLL from theme developer that does not add Google Maps API javascript and that has fixed this issue.